# String representation of small amounts of money

Tags: c#, .net, currency

Formatting large amounts of money is not an issue (e.g. converting a decimal to dollars):

```
myDecimal.ToString("C", {some culture info});
```

However, my current problem is dealing with very small amounts of money (e.g. cents/pence, etc.) and rather than formatting 5 cents as $0.05 (or 5 pence as £0.05), I need to format as 5¢ or 5p.  Is there anything built in to the .NET framework to handle this?  Or am I stuck rolling my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that you're on your own, I'm afraid. Sorry that doesn't help much.

There is only [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx) - nothing more granular.

Comment: You appear to be correct.  The CurrencySymbol only gives the $ sign, but it's easy enough to roll my own class using the NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits and a reference like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_(currency).  I'm struggling to find a better currency resource for fractions on the main unit of curency, though.  I don't necessarily trust wikipedia...